# Making Android code cross platform

Tags: android, jquery, ios, sqlite, porting

My Android app uses dynamic UI. That is, all of it UI screens are made up of only simple types  (gallery, list view, form view) and they are created entirely by java code instead of using xml templates. This is because there is hardly anything static in the UI. Also the java code uses sqlite extensively. There is no media stuff (images, videos) and it is a plain database front end app. Also it doesn't use much of device capabilities (camera, SMS etc).

There are 3 major areas - SQLite files, pure Java code which does NOT have any Android dependency, Android UI java code (ListView etc - but only pretty thin code). I need to make all of these work in iOS.

What are my choices to make this code cross platform (atleast port to iOS)? jQuery Mobile? PhoneGap? Any other? Thanks!

Comment: If you can write your logic in C++, you can use it on both platforms.  If you prefer to keep your sanity, I recommend against third party multiplatform tools.

Comment: PhoneGap is a good choice for a cross platform app. But then you would have to rewrite everything.

Comment: I don't want write entire thing in C++ again. Most (90%) of my code pure java code that runs on desktop without modification. I just need to generate something out of it which works on iOS.

Comment: http://www.codenameone.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Google Project [`j2objc`](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc)?

Comment: But For this u need mac and iPhone SDK

Comment: I just came across this a few minutes ago. I will definitely give it a try. Will it work for "pure non-Android" java code? Also came across these links: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/178 and http://www.infoworld.com/t/java-programming/gosling-new-java-proposal-could-ease-ports-ios-213843